# Syntax error em um programa besta em Python

Tags: python, sintaxe, basic

```
modo = int(input("Selecionar modo de jogo: "))

if modo == 1
print("deu 1")

if modo == 2
print("deu 2")
```

---

Eu queria só testar se o usuário, quando digitasse 2 o programa imprimisse 2 e o mesmo pro 1, mas ta dando syntax error, algm me ajuda

Comment: 1) Indentação, ela é obrigatória no Python. Blocos de código dentro do `if` devem estar indentados em relação a ele; 2) Falta os dois pontos, `:`, no final de todos os `if`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que eu estou vendo o seu código possui uma série de erros:

1. Identação: quando você for usar um `if`, a próxima linha deve conter 4 espaços em relação à linha de cima.
2. Quando chamada a função `if` e suas condições, deve haver o sinal de dois pontos (:) em seguida para que o python consiga assimilar que aquilo é um bloco de código.
3. Este último erro não é em relação ao código mas sim à sua pergunta, você leu o artigo sobre como fazer uma boa pergunta no stackoverflow? Sugiro que dê uma olhada e conserte isso ai :).

Em relação ao seu problema, este aqui é o código que você procura:

```py
modo = int(input("Selecionar modo de jogo: "))

if modo == 1:
    print("deu 1")

if modo == 2:
    print("deu 2")
```

Comment: Não li, fiz isso meio correndo pq precisaria pra amanhã, mas vou dar uma olhada dps de ver umas aulas tbm, obrigado.

Comment: @Kah, se a resposta foi satisfatória para o seu problema, por favor, marque-a como aceita, e nós dois ganhamos pontos. É so clicar no 'V' do lado esquerdo da minha resposta, obrigado! :)